# Events not propogating downwards from psuedo element

Tags: css, web, dom-events

I have the following code, when i hover the overlay reveals whats below it, however this overlay stops me from interacting from the content below it.

I need to interact with content in .media, but .card-overlay blocks it. I have tried pointer-events:none; that works, but then the hover animation will not work and reveal the .media content below it

```
          & #card {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 50vh;
            margin-bottom: 9%;
            //border: 3px solid red;
            //flex: 0% 1 auto;

            & .media {
              position: relative;
              // border: 3px solid green;
              video {
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 50vh;
                height: auto;
                object-fit: cover;
                z-index: 15; 
              }

              & .sketchfab-embed-wrapper {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                cursor: pointer;
                pointer-events: auto;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
                & iframe {
                  z-index: 1;
                  // border: 3px solid red;
                  position: relative;
                  width: 179%;
                  height: 100%;
                }
              }
            }

            & .card-overlay {
              left: 0px;
              top: 0px;
              position: absolute;
              // border: 3px solid green;
              z-index: 16;
              height: 100%;
              padding: 1%;
              opacity: 100%;
              width: 100%;

              &::after {
                content: '';
                -webkit-border-radius: var(--border);
                -moz-border-radius: var(--border);
                -ms-border-radius: var(--border);
                -o-border-radius: var(--border);
                border-radius: var(--border);
                background: randomColor();
                height: 100%;
                mix-blend-mode: normal;
                width: 100%;
                // border: 2px solid red;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                z-index: 1;
                transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -webkit-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -moz-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -ms-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -o-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
              }

              &:hover::after {
                mix-blend-mode: difference;
                //opacity: 50%;
                background-color: var(--clr-fourth);
                width: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -webkit-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -moz-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -ms-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
                -o-transition: width .5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "pointer-events: auto;" to .media (the child) when "pointer-events: none;" is used on .card-overlay (the parent)?

Comment: Hover animation stops working, so the events are not bubbling from bottom to top like I think you were suggesting. I think this has to be done with JavaScript, I'm not sure how though

Comment: I see, in that case, you should try making it so that when you hover on the parent element of ".card-overlay", that you set "pointer-events: none;" to activate on ".card-overlay", I'm fairly sure that would allow you to click through ".card-overlay" to ".media". I hope that makes sense, let me know if not (assuming you've not already sorted the issue by now).

Comment: then the hover will break since its no longer tracking whether the mouse is inside the div.

Comment: I mean like this `.parent:hover > .card-overlay{pointer-events: none;}`? What should happen is, when the parent element for card-overlay(whether it is a div or any other element) is hovered over, the css properties of .card-overlay change. meaning that the hover shouldn't break.

Comment: That hasnt worked, the content below the overlay stops responding and there isnt any hover effect any longer